# Grammatical class of 'we' when referring to a collective group vs each individual of a group

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar, grammatical-person

What's the grammatical class of "we" when referring to a group in its entirety versus when referring to each individual member of the group.

For example, if I said to my girlfriend:

> *We* will be okay [us as a couple], but regardless, *we* will be okay [as two individuals, regardless of the status of our relationship].

Clearly both uses of 'we' are referring to both the first and second person, however there is a clear difference in meaning. The same is apparent in this next (intentionally ambiguous) example of a company memo:

> *We* must be politically neutral [as an organization], however *we* can do whatever *we* want [as individuals when not representing the organization].

I can't figure out how these uses of 'we' are distinguished in a grammatical sense. It doesn't make sense to say that the first usage is the inclusive 'we' whilst the second usage is the exclusive 'we', as both instances are referring to both the first and second persons.

I know that in both of these cases the ambiguity can be cleared up by using additional words, but that's beside the point, as there should be a way to differentiate between the uses from an analytical standpoint (i.e. how we distinguish between the inclusive and exclusive uses).

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer, but maybe you're referring to agency: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_(grammar)
In the statement "we must be politically neutral", it seems to me that the agent in that case is the organization itself, whereas making a statement such as "we are permitted to work remotely twice per week", the agent in that case would be the particular members of the organization (the organization itself cannot do remote work).

Comment: (With just one exception), its part of speech (your grammatical class) is noun. Pronouns are a subclass of noun.

Comment: I don't think there is a designated term for this important concept. Certainly, 'inclusive we' includes all 'concerned' while 'exclusive we' means 'we as opposed to you', and is a different classification. 'Collective _we_' and 'individuated _we_' suggest themselves, but are unidiomatic and would need defining if used. 'We as individuals' and 'we collectively' are the usual ways of addressing the different cases, but the duality itself hasn't, as far as I'm aware, an accepted name.

Comment: Agreeing with Edwin, I had a look around the relevant Wikipedia articles on number, pronouns, etc, and couldn't see this distinction mentioned (although they're not particularly good or thorough articles).

Comment: Are you saying that anyone would actually say to someone "we shall be okay and we shall be okay."?  Surely not.  There has to be a context built around these two statements to allow them to make sense.  You can say "we are a man and a woman." 
 Ancient Greek, as it happens, had a special part of verbs and nouns to refer specifically to pairs, and called the 'dual'.  But even that would not help.  The recent dramatisation of Sally Roony's novel  'Normal People', ends with Connell:  "I'll go."; Marianne: "And I'll stay.  And we'll be okay."  So the 'we' is each separately. Context made it work.

Comment: You have nailed the critical purpose of *restrictive clauses*: We must be politically neutral as an organization, and do whatever we want as individuals when not representing the organization. Deleting the brackets reveals the distinctions you need.

Comment: The distinction is close to the inclusive/exclusive first person plural. _We_ (inclusive) includes the addressee, while _we_ (exclusive) excludes the addressee. [In Indonesian, _kami_ is exclusive, while _kita_ is inclusive.](https://lingo-apps.com/kami-vs-kita/). In English, _we_ can mean either: _Are we there yet?_ (inclusive), _We'll be leaving you with the dishes_ (exclusive). Most English speakers never notice the difference.

Comment: And then there’s the royal *we*.

Comment: In response to Tuffy, that example is actually one I found myself trying to say in person, which prompted this question. I wanted to emphasise that we'd be okay as individuals in a more poetic manner than "you and I individually will be okay" (which is what I ended up having to say).

Comment: By 'there should be a way to differentiate between the uses from an analytical standpoint (i.e. how we distinguish between the inclusive and exclusive uses)' I assume you mean 'there should be terminology more suitable than _'we as individuals' "we"_ (as in 'we were born in different states') and _'we as a group' "we"_ (as in 'we were beaten by a better side'). I'm not sure there is. The different usages involved here generally aren't even mentioned in dictionaries. // Disambiguation is necessary, a bare 'We will meet various problems in life' / 'We will get married' (!) being indeterminate.

Comment: If you're after such terminology, please clarify and alter your tags. If, on the other hand, you're asking **how** to differentiate the two senses without context / extra wording  (actually, these are not the only ways 'we' is used) ... they're inherently ambiguous. You can't.

Comment: @Geordan Nicholson.  Without context, the meaning of sentences like the OP's has a meaning based on probability rather than grammar or semantics.  The same would apply equally to the 3rd person.  This brings us to Gricean meaning intention (or "intension", as he put it).  In 'Normal People' I take it that she meaning each of them will be okay, whether as a couple or separately.  But what if she already had a lover he was unaware of? Then unknown to Connor, she is speaking ironically to deceive.  The same sentence would be, in a sense, both true and untrue: or, at least, a deception.

Answer (score 1):

One should not confuse grammar with semantics. **Grammatically,** the two uses of *we* are the same.

I am assuming that in both uses you have in mind, it is not acceptable to precede the *we* by an article (unlike what I have just done). Otherwise, it's a different story. For example, consider the sentence *We are a 'we'.* In this case, the first *we* is a pronoun, but the second is a noun (because it is preceded by an article)—a clear difference in grammar.

### Discussion

**Motivating example: *bank***

Consider the situation with the word *bank*. That word has two quite different meanings: *bank<sub>1</sub>* is a financial institution, and *bank<sub>2</sub>* is sloping land on the side of a river. But despite the *lexical* difference, *bank<sub>1</sub>* and *bank<sub>2</sub>* are indistinguishable as far as their grammatical properties. Grammatically, both *bank<sub>1</sub>* and *bank<sub>2</sub>* are countable nouns, with the plural *banks*. They can both be the subject of the sentence (*A **bank** recently collapsed*), the object of a verb (*We will demolish that **bank***), a predictive complement (*That is a **bank***), the head of a complicated noun phrase (*even all the old **banks** in Italy that still exist*), etc.

There is a possibility that one might detect a difference in how the two *banks* interact with other words, e.g. prepositions. For example, for all I know, there could be some prepositions that are licensed by *bank<sub>1</sub>*, but not *bank<sub>2</sub>* (or vice-versa). However, I am not aware of any such difference. For example, *I'm going to the bank* is grammatical regardless of whether the *bank* in question is *bank<sub>1</sub>* or *bank<sub>2</sub>*. Even *he's in the bank* is grammatical for both (though it is much more likely to be used with *bank<sub>1</sub>*).

***We***

The situation with *we<sub>1</sub>* (each individual member of the group) and *we<sub>2</sub>* (a group in its entirety) is similar.

Both *we<sub>1</sub>* and  *we<sub>2</sub>* disallow determiners, which is a distinguishing characteristic of pronouns. Both  *we<sub>1</sub>* and  *we<sub>2</sub>* have the same inflectional forms: *us* (accusative), *our* (dependent genitive), *ours* (independent genitive), and *ourselves* (reflexive). In the nominative, they can both be subjects of a sentence; in the accusative, they can be objects; and so on and so on.

More generally, I don't know of any constructions that are grammatical with *we<sub>1</sub>* but not  *we<sub>2</sub>*, or vice versa.

The difference between *we<sub>1</sub>* from *we<sub>2</sub>* is thus not grammatical, but lexical. It should be recorded not in grammar books, but in dictionaries. Unfortunately, as best as I can tell, dictionaries only record *we<sub>1</sub>*. And why that might be the case is certainly an interesting question, which I currently have no idea how to answer.

***We* as a noun in the OED**

The following entry in OED at first seems to cover *we<sub>2</sub>*, but the annotation *n.* shows that this *we* is a noun, which is confirmed by the fact that this *we* takes an article in the sample sentence:

> **B.** *n.*
> **2.**
> **b.** A couple or group identified to its members by the word ‘we’; two or more people forming a unit.
> 1979   E. Hardwick *Sleepless Nights* v. 61   I am alone here in New York, no longer a *we*.